# Error: - Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: tomcat

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Garage</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <resource-ref>
 <description>GarageDB Datasource</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/garage</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

I can't seem to fix this error. I have attached a link to my github and the file. Please help.[click here for the link](http://github.com/damienj252/Data_Centric_RAD). I am using tomcat version 9.0 and using wampserver to try fix this error and I have already imported the java sql converter mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.

Comment: This is a class path problem.  Are you using Maven or Gradle by chance?

Comment: Run "jar tf mssql-connector-java.jar" to confirm the file is present and contains com/sql/jdbc/Driver.class

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your "mssql-connector-java" jar file, paste it into "lib" folder of your current project (i.e present in webcontent>WEBINF>lib), and rerun the application.

Comment: Thanks @Basavaraj I have tried that but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your jar file in the tomcat server directory - in case you're using windows it's : **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib**  , and don't forget to restart the server.